# iPad/iPhone L2TP VPN locks up SonicWall NSA2400 Randomly

Tags: vpn, sonicwall, l2tp, ipad

Ok so I've got iPad/iPhone's connecting to my network via L2TP VPN setup interfacing with a Sonicwall NSA 2400 gateway.  The problem is that sometimes when the iPad/iPhone is connected over the VPN but goes to sleep, when it wakes up it sometimes crashes my gateway!  I wanted to check with folks here before I started flipping VPN options off and on randomly, any thoughts are appreciated!